# How can i get simple makefile tutorial without compilers

Tags: linux, centos, make, makefile

In my project our coder have written the `makefile` for installing and deploying the web application like

`make install.php`

which then contain instructions to install it.

I am searching google and you tube for makefile tutorial but all teches how to comiple c files. no tutorial is telling to automate the installation process or deployment

Comment: Instead of asking for tutorials, please ask about what specific issue you need to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt provide all that by default, it was designed in a time when php probably didnt exist..

The most basic tutorials will say that the format is similar to below

```
<target> : < prerequisites> 
    <shell command>
```

Where target might be files, prerequisites are optional but typically are files. Based on this you could replace the shell command with whatever you want and it will work with a simple `make <target>`

Maybe this will inspire - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395234/any-interesting-uses-of-makefiles-to-share